# How to run a script after Xcode runs codesign on my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, build-process, scripting, build-automation, adhoc

I've got a script written which does some steps to package my build for an Ad Hoc distribution. My first guess was to use a run script phase in my Ad Hoc target. But it looks like codesigning is fixed at the last position in the chain of building iPhone apps.

Somebody has a clue how can I run my script at the very last possible moment in the build process?

**Update:** Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409981/how-to-run-a-script-after-xcode-runs-codesign-on-my-iphone-app/7345627#7345627) below on how to run scripts in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you create an aggregate target that contains both your "Ad hoc" target and a run script build phase (that runs after the "Ad hoc" target)?

Answer (score 17):

A short update on that topic: Since we all use Xcode 4 these days. Apple has refined the process of running scripts on several events in the build process with the introduction of schemes.

Go to <kbd>Product</kbd> → <kbd>Edit Scheme…</kbd> and expand the Build side bar item, there you have the chance to run scripts before (Pre-actions) and after (Post-actions) a build, a debugging, archiving, etc event. It's pretty handy to set a *version number* from `git describe` output or upload .xcarchives to services like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) and [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/).

If you want to share your pre/post scripts with other team members who got access to your code repository, you can go to <kbd>Product</kbd> → <kbd>Manage Schemes…</kbd> and mark your scheme as *shared*. After you checked in `…{project_name}.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/{project_name}.xcscheme` to your preferred [scm](/questions/tagged/scm) everybody can use it in the project.

Comment: Thanks. I came across this issue today where I needed the shell script to run after code signing. This really helped me out.