# iPhone: Compressing .app files in command line (Mac OS X) removes CodeSigning

Tags: iphone, zip, codesign, .app

I am trying to do a simple build automation of my iPhone apps with TeamCity, but having this nagging issue..

When I manually pickup and install .app file from the build folder it works great (syncs smoothly with iTunes and I can see the app on my phone)

But when I try to zip this with /bin/zip or ditto...then the zipped contents loose the CodeSigning (iTunes says that it cannot install this app because its not signed)

I have tried different combinations of these..

ditto -ck --rsrc --keepParent HelloWorld.app HelloWorld.zip

Any more ideas?

I tried this too but still getting the same error

```
version=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S")
cd "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"
zip -r -y "HelloWorld-$version.zip" HelloWorld.app
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the -y option on zip:

```
zip -r -y zipped_blahapp.zip blahapp.app
```

> -y
>
> Store symbolic links as such in the zip archive, instead of compressing
>   and storing the file referred to by
>   the link (UNIX only).

*Update*

Now the Xcode archive functionality is available from the command line, you should probably be using that:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace $APPNAME.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme $APPSCHEMENAME > $OUTDIR/logs/$APPNAME.log
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response but still getting the same issue, I have edited my question with the exact script I am using..

Comment: @Santthosh Sorry you are still having the issue.  I had exactly the same problem and adding -y resolved it for me.  You script looks good to me.  I'll update if I find any more info on this problem.

Comment: Sorry you were right...

I was zipping before the CodeSign was happening (listed in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409981/how-to-run-a-script-after-xcode-runs-codesign-on-my-iphone-app)

Comment: @Santthos Awesome ... glad you got it sorted :)