# UNIX ZIP(1L) doesn't include top Directory of Application

Tags: zip, applescript

I made, better I rummage together an AppleScript that results encrypted zip Files. It works except for Applications. If I expand the Archiv it is not an Application anymore. How can I compress valid Applications?

```
  tell application "Finder"
    set theItem to ((choose file) as alias)
    set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
    set fileName to name of theItem
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
    set zipFile to quoted form of (theFolder & fileName & ".zip")
    display dialog "Enter password" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    set thePassword to (text returned of result)
end tell
set cmd to "zip -P " & thePassword & " -rj " & zipFile & " " & itemPath & " -x *.DS_Store"
do shell script cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `-y` option for zip. It may be what you need.

From [iPhone: Compressing .app files in command line (Mac OS X) removes CodeSigning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878797/iphone-compressing-app-files-in-command-line-mac-os-x-removes-codesigning)