# Workflow for debugging PhoneGap using Safari's Web Inspector

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, workflow, safari-web-inspector

I'm developing a phone gap app and [using Safari's Web Inspector to debug it](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html). The tool is very useful but there are a couple workflow inefficiencies that are costing me some time.

1. Every time I stop my PhoneGap app in xCode the Safari Web Inspector window automatically closes leaving me with the task of re-opening it every time I make a change and re-launch the app.
2. The only way I'm able to get a full read out in the console is by entering window.location.reload(). Again this adds a step to my work flow everytime I deploy a change in xCode.

Does anyone know how to set it up so that Safari Web Inspector stays open and the console automatically monitors the app?

Answer (score 5):

To solve the reload issue, I add this in my head section when I'm debugging:

```
<script>
  alert('connect your debugger, if you want')
</script>
```

The alert stops all execution, meaning that I can (manually, ugh) connect my debugger and not miss anything. Execution resumes when I hit okay on the alert window.

Comment: You sure know how JS works. Very smart move! thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issues. I haven't solved them yet, and I'm running out of time, so I'll show you what I've got so far:

Create an ActionScript that opens the web inspector:

https://gist.github.com/amuino/5649177 **This works!**

Have Xcode launch it! I tried creating a shell script that, in turn, opens the action script, but to no avail. This is what I've got:

[How to run a script after Xcode runs codesign on my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409981/how-to-run-a-script-after-xcode-runs-codesign-on-my-iphone-app)

Comment: Can't get it run post build , any Idea on why ? Got the script working as long as I execute it by terminal..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way around this issue. It's not super elegant but it works.

At the entry point of my app I added some delay with setTimeout, like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    app.init();
}, 10000);
```

This will give you enough time (10 seconds) to reopen Safari Web Inspector and you will get full console read out.

It saved me a lot of headache.